# How to update RecyclerView dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update a recyclerView every 60 seconds with adding new items to the recycler view.

I would like to have your advise about using a background service to be able to retrieve new data from server and then update the recyclerview

To do that I have to request the server every 60 seconds, to do that I'm trying this test code :

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate
        (new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mAdapter.addItem(new Post("Yahhooo"));

                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);

            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

and my Recyclerview looks like :

```
public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Post> mDataset;


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtHeader;
        public ImageView pub_image;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstline);
            pub_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        }
    }


    public FeedAdapter(List<Post> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;

    }

    @Override
    public FeedAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feedholder, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
    public void addItem(Post item) {
        mDataset.add(item);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position).getPost_text());

        Picasso.with(holder.pub_image.getContext()).load("http://www.vivamexico.info/Peintures/DiegoRivera/Ere-01.jpg").into(holder.pub_image);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

It works only for one time, then it shows this error :

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

for the line `mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing your RecyclerView from the scheduled worker thread, you cannot update views from anything but the main UI thread.

`mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);` is the culprit.

Without knowing the entire architecture of your app I can only give you this advice: You can use a `Handler` created with the main looper to post that call back to the main thread.

```
Handler mainThread = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
...
// In your worker thread
mainThread.post(new Runnable() {
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
});
```

If you really just want to add an item every N seconds you could just use `Handler.postDelayed()` and keep re-posting until you want to stop. There's no need for the worker thread.